# Conflicting Constraints Error Message in Debugger

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints

I'm working through an online tutorial. I have followed everything step by step and am getting a message in the debugger when running the simulator saying I have conflicting constraints. I don't believe there is conflicting constraints, so I figured I would reach out for an informed second opinion.

Here is a screenshot of the view controller with the conflicting constraints.

[View Controller from Xcode Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDevT.png)

Here are the screenshots of the error message in the debugger: It looks like it has an issue with the width constraint on the stop button, but I can't tell from the error message how to fix it.

[Part of Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TbHt.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: First remove height: 64 for from last stackView

Comment: @jaydeepVyas then the bottom stackView will take up half of the screen.

Comment: i have given answer below see that

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you set stop button width = 64 but actual you not set width for parent view so it automatic set equal to 0 or 343.
Did you get any red constraints when click on stop button?

Comment: The only constraint I have when clicking on the button is the width constraint that is setup. I tried to set the constraint for the stack view containing the stop button to a width of 64 as well, but that didn't do any good. I still get a huge long error message.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the answer. I had to change the priority to 999 on the width constraint of the stop button. The debug message was saying the below constraints were in conflict.

```
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000096080 UIButton:0x7fb874e157d0.width == 64   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000097ac0 'fittingSizeHTarget' UIStackView:0x7fb874e155d0.width == 0   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000096210 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x7fb874e155d0.leading <= UIButton:0x7fb874e157d0.leading   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000097ca0 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x7fb874e155d0.centerX == UIButton:0x7fb874e157d0.centerX   (active)>"
)
```

Then it said it needed to break the width constraint of the stop button in order to fix the conflicting constraints issue.

```
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000096080 UIButton:0x7fb874e157d0.width == 64   
(active)>
```

Dropping the priority to 999 prevented the debug message from appearing, and kept the buttons were I wanted them.

I found the solution information here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/DebuggingTricksandTips.html

[From the link]
Of these constraints, the last one was created by the system. You cannot change it. Furthermore, it creates an obvious conflict with the first constraint. If you superview is only 320 points wide, you can never have a 400-point-wide label. Fortunately, you don’t have to get rid of the first constraint. If you drop its priority to 999, the system still tries to provide the selected width—coming as close as it can while still satisfying the other constraints.